# How to resolve component with two levels of nested routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two levels of settings pages in my app.  The first level is off the main App:

```
    import { Home, Progress, Settings, Error } from "./screens";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={() => <Home />} />
              <Route path="/One/:id" component={() => <One />} />
   Here -->   <Route path="/Settings" component={() => <Settings />} />
              <Route component={() => <Error />} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

The second level is an Advanced Settings page off of the Settings page:

```
    import AdvancedSettings from "../components/settings/AdvancedSettings";
    
    export default function Settings() {
      let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Settings</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${url}/Defaults1`}>Defaults1</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${url}/Defaults2`}>Defaults2</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              **<Link exact to={`${url}/AdvancedSettings`}>Advanced Settings</Link>**
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link>Restart</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
    
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={path}>
              <h3>Please select</h3>
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/Defaults1`}>
              <Defaults1 />
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/Defaults2`}>
              <Defaults2 />
            </Route>
 Here -->   <Route path={`${path}/AdvancedSettings`}>
              <AdvancedSettings />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Here's the code for my second level:

```
import AdjustSettings from "../components/settings/AdjustSettings";

export default function AdvancedSettings() {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Advanced Settings</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/AdjustSettings`}>Adjust Advanced Settings</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/AdjustSettings`}>
          <AdjustSettings />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when trying to compile I get an error in my second level:

Module not found: Can't resolve '../components/settings/AdjustSettings'.

I know that component is good as I can use it elsewhere with the same import path.
What could be causing the component to not be found using my layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using relative routes solved this for me.

Create a file in the root: jsconfig.json

Put these settings in it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src"
    }
  }
```